# for loop gives key error in for loop i am giving lists

Tags: python, algorithmic-trading

i am trying to backtest strategy for my algotrading environment
in for loop it check compare the lists value and gives output signal buy or sell after that it store value in dataframe

tried by lists to dataframe but gives everytime keyerror from pandas

```py
for i in range(len(merged_DF)):    

    if signal == "":
        stock_ret.append(0)
        if i > 0:
            if bar_num[i]>=2 and macd[i]>macd_sig[i] and macd_slope[i]>macd_sig_slope[i]:
                signal = "Buy"
            elif bar_num[i]<=-2 and macd[i]<macd_sig[i] and macd_slope[i]<macd_sig_slope[i]:
                signal = "Sell"

    elif signal == "Buy":
        stock_ret.append((merged_DF["close"][i]/merged_DF["close"][i-1])-1)
        if i > 0:
            if bar_num[i]<=-2 and macd[i]<macd_sig[i] and macd_slope[i]<macd_sig_slope[i]:
                signal = "Sell"
            elif macd[i]<macd_sig[i] and macd_slope[i]<macd_sig_slope[i]:
                signal = ""

    elif signal == "Sell":
        stock_ret.append((merged_DF["close"][i-1]/merged_DF["close"][i])-1)
        if i > 0:
            if bar_num[i]>=2 and macd[i]>macd_sig[i] and macd_slope[i]>macd_sig_slope[i]:
                signal = "Buy"
            elif macd[i]>macd_sig[i] and macd_slope[i]>macd_sig_slope[i]:
                signal = ""
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-26-b5a1f393f490>", line 12, in <module>
    stock_ret.append((merged_DF["close"][i]/merged_DF["close"][i-1])-1)

  File "c:\users\ramakrishnamekala\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 1071, in __getitem__
    result = self.index.get_value(self, key)

  File "c:\users\ramakrishnamekala\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 4730, in get_value
    return self._engine.get_value(s, k, tz=getattr(series.dtype, "tz", None))

  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 80, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value

  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 88, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value

  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 131, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 992, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item

  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 998, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item

KeyError: 2
```

signal = buy or sell or None

Comment: `merged_DF["close"]` is probably a dictionary. You're using an index to access it.

Comment: Can you show us a sample of your input data? And if possible what are you trying to achieve (desired output)?